# SugarCRM: Custom Module assigned_to_user field not saving 'id' value

Tags: module, field, sugarcrm

I'm designing a Custom Module named Agents, using **ModuleBuilder** in **SugarCE 6.0.0**.

The module is based on Accounts. In Studio, when I click on **assigned_user_name** from the **Assignable** section and save it, it generates two fields, namely:

- **assigned_user_name**
- **_id_c**

When I deployed the package and tried to pick a username from the assigned to field, at first it wouldn't fetch any results at all (neither through autofill nor popup).

I checked out the **custom/modulebuilder/packages/MyPackage/modules/Agents/vardefs.php**, here's what I found:

```
'_id_c' => 
array (
  'required' => false,
  'name' => '_id_c',
  'vname' => '',
  'type' => 'id',
  'massupdate' => 0,
  'comments' => '',
  'help' => '',    
  'importable' => 'true',
  'duplicate_merge' => 'disabled',
  'duplicate_merge_dom_value' => 0,
  'audited' => false,
  'reportable' => true,
  'len' => 36,
  'size' => '20',
),
'assigned_user_name' => 
array (
  'required' => true,
  'name' => 'assigned_user_name',
  'link' => 'assigned_user_link',
  'vname' => 'LBL_ASSIGNED_TO_NAME',
  'rname' => 'name',
  'type' => 'relate',
  'reportable' => true,
  'source' => 'non-db',
  'table' => 'users',
  'id_name' => '_id_c',
  'module' => '',
  'duplicate_merge' => 'disabled',
  'massupdate' => 0,
  'comments' => '',
  'help' => '',
  'importable' => 'true',
  'duplicate_merge_dom_value' => '0',
  'audited' => true,
  'len' => '255',
  'size' => '20',
  'ext2' => '',
  'quicksearch' => 'enabled',
  'studio' => 'visible',
),
```

Note that the **module** option in assigned_user_name is not being set to the right value. 
First question: Is this a Studio bug?

My quick fix was to set `module => 'Users'` and it worked. I was now able to select the username from a dropdown (autofill) list.

However, selecting a username still doesn't populate the hidden **_id_c** field with the 36 Char UUID of the user and hence, when I save the record and reload it, the assigned_user_name field remains blank.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is happening? And any remedies for this?

Thanks,
m^e

Answer (score 1):

Well don't think you should be getting these in your vardefs because these fields are defined in parent class which all modules extend. By default these are the fields that are user for assigned user:

```
var $assigned_user_id;
var $assigned_user_name;
var $assigned_user_link;
```

By looking at your code you can try setting:

```
'id_name' => 'assigned_user_id'
```

You are not supposed to create additional field for this field `(_id_c)`.